# Creating an adjustable output regulator, in LTspice

Tags: ltspice

Firstly, I'm having some trouble with simulating a variable resistor in LTspice.. I am wondering if this can be done?

Also, does anyone have any advice on how to theoretically analyse this circuit? I mean, the data sheet gives a formula for Vo but I think it's a little vague, any pointers in the right direction to derive this would be great as well.

[image: Adjustable Output Regulator]

Comment: "but am unsure how to replicate it physically" - it's a variable resistor - you buy one not build one.

Comment: It's pretty unclear to me what you mean by that statement as well, do you mean how to physically build the overall circuit? If you're referring to understanding the physics behind it then it's not a very clear way to express it.

Comment: @PeterJ I think he was being sarcastic in his comment but I'm glad someone else was confused by what he said.

Comment: Sorry if the question was vague, I will be able to build this circuit... My two main questions were, how to analyse the circuit, which andy has answered.. The other is how can i simulate the 10k resistor in LTspice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output voltage of a 7805 is 5V relative to pin 2 - if pin 2 is raised a volt above ground then the output voltage is 6 volts relative to ground. Because there will always be a small (and fairly constant) current flowing to ground from pin 2 (usually about 4mA =\$I_Q\$), the offset voltage on pin 2 can be 1V (if R is 250 ohms) or if you wish to do it more accurately you can use two resistors, R1 and R2 forming a potential divider from the output to ground. This uses the more complex formula in your question and \$I_Q\$ is as stated above i.e. about 4mA. \$V_{XX}\$ is the output voltage if pin 2 were grounded i.e. 5V for a 7805.

However, your circuit uses an op-amp to raise pin 2 so whatever voltage is at the output of the op-amp adds to the 5V on the output just as if you inserted one resistor in the common line.

Comment: Note that as drawn the design will not reliably produce an output below about 7 V because of the common mode range of the '741.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily simulate a variable resistor with the C-E junction of an optoisolator, but as I recall there are some much better models available from the LTspice user group at:

http://groups.yahoo.com/group/LTspice/